# Java findHomography transform image point to ground plane point

Tags: java, opencv, homography, perspectivecamera

**Objective**: Take a point (or set of points) from a camera perspective view and translate it/them to the respective ground plane points.

**Approach:** Used `findHomography` to obtain a homography `Mat`. Plan to use `perspectiveTransform()`.

**Issue:** Cannot interpret homography `Mat`, nor understand how to continue. It appears 5 of the 9 elements are null, which I take to mean that the homography is faulty, though have no way of interpreting the results, so a made a number of print statements.

```
import org.opencv.calib3d.*;
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint2f;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.highgui.Highgui;
import org.opencv.imgproc.*;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.ArrayList;

final public class HomographyTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME); // needed by OpenCV

        String rfileoutput = "/home/will/dev/Homog.jpg";
        String ofileoutput = "/home/will/dev/HomogOutput.jpg";

        Point SEShedCornerDst = new Point(49, 74);
        Point CloseForsythiaDst = new Point(41, 41);
        Point CornerHazelDst = new Point(111, 157);
        Point FarForsythiaDst = new Point(175, 21);
        Point FirstLiquidAmberDst = new Point(235, 164);
        Point SecondLiquidAmberDst = new Point(282, 721);
        Point ThirdLiquidAmberDst = new Point(317, 544);

        Point SEShedCornerSrc = new Point(30, 231);
        Point CloseForsythiaSrc = new Point(160, 290);
        Point CornerHazelSrc = new Point(50, 125);
        Point FarForsythiaSrc = new Point(628, 146);
        Point FirstLiquidAmberSrc = new Point(299, 64);
        Point SecondLiquidAmberSrc = new Point(146, 37);
        Point ThirdLiquidAmberSrc = new Point(48,34);

        Point [] srcArray = new Point[7];
        srcArray[0] = SEShedCornerSrc;
        srcArray[1] = CloseForsythiaSrc;
        srcArray[2] = CornerHazelSrc;
        srcArray[3] = FarForsythiaSrc;
        srcArray[4] = FirstLiquidAmberSrc;
        srcArray[5] = SecondLiquidAmberSrc;
        srcArray[6] = ThirdLiquidAmberSrc;

        Mat OutputMat = new Mat();
        LinkedList<Point> dstArray = new LinkedList<Point>();

        dstArray.add(SEShedCornerDst);
        dstArray.add(CloseForsythiaDst);        
        dstArray.add(CornerHazelDst);
        dstArray.add(FarForsythiaDst);
        dstArray.add(FirstLiquidAmberDst);
        dstArray.add(SecondLiquidAmberDst);
        dstArray.add(ThirdLiquidAmberDst);

        MatOfPoint2f dst = new MatOfPoint2f();
        dst.fromList(dstArray);

        MatOfPoint2f src = new MatOfPoint2f();
        src.fromArray(srcArray);

        Mat Homog;


        Homog = Calib3d.findHomography(src, dst, Calib3d.RANSAC, 10, OutputMat);

        System.out.println("Columns = " + Homog.cols());
        System.out.println("Rows = " + Homog.rows());
        System.out.println("Width = " + Homog.width());
        System.out.println("Dims = " + Homog.dims());

        for (int i=1; i<= Homog.cols();i++){
            for (int j=1; j<=Homog.rows();j++){
                System.out.println("Row, column " + i + "," + j + " = " + Homog.get(j, i));
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println(Homog.toString());
        System.out.println(OutputMat.toString());
        Highgui.imwrite(rfileoutput, Homog);
        Highgui.imwrite(ofileoutput, OutputMat);
    }
}
```

The output;

```
Columns = 3
Rows = 3
Width = 3
Dims = 2
Row, column 1,1 = [D@674f1c67
Row, column 1,2 = [D@7ad1e32d
Row, column 1,3 = null

Row, column 2,1 = [D@6999de59
Row, column 2,2 = [D@74d4db38
Row, column 2,3 = null

Row, column 3,1 = null
Row, column 3,2 = null
Row, column 3,3 = null

Mat [ 3*3*CV_64FC1, isCont=true, isSubmat=false, nativeObj=0x7f744016bb50, dataAddr=0x7f744016b940 ]
Mat [ 7*1*CV_8UC1, isCont=true, isSubmat=false, nativeObj=0x7f7440166fe0, dataAddr=0x7f744016b9b0 ]
```

Am I on the right track? If not, what should I do?

If so, what type is entered into the src `Mat` for `perspectiveTransform`, and how do I do that in the two channels it says is required?

http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/Core.html#perspectiveTransform(org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't really interpret your code, especially your points but I don't think it matters because as you said your objective is to create a homography matrix from 2 sets of points and perspectively transform an image with the resulting homography matrix.

**Iterating through the homography matrix**

First of all the reason why you get `null` from your iteration through the homography matrix (which is a 3x3 matrix) is because `Mat` indices start just like arrays at 0 and end at "length - 1".

It should look something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < homography.cols(); i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < homography.rows(); j++){
        System.out.println("[" + i + "," + j + "] = " + Arrays.toString(homography.get(j, i)));
    }
}
```

**Find homography and apply (to image)**

And to find the homography matrix between your `src` and `dst` planes you can use `findHomography()`. For more information on this function, it's parameters look in the [API](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html)

```
// obtain your homography mat (picked your parameters.. you have to play to get the right results)
Mat homography = Calib3d.findHomography(src, dst, Calib3d.RANSAC, 10);
// image you want to transform
Mat image = Highgui.imread("image/img.jpg");
// outputMat will contain the perspectively changed image
Imgproc.warpPerspective(image, outputMat, homography, new Size(image.cols(), image.rows()));
```

**Applying homography to single points (not an image)**

```
Mat src = new Mat();
// push a mat object with your points to the src
src.push_back(new MatOfPoint2f(new Point(x,y)));
// dst will contain your transformed points
Core.perspectiveTransform(src, dst, homography)
```

Btw..

In Java it is common practice to start variable names with lowercase letters. I saw `Homog` and `OutputMat`. When I read something like that I expect them to be classes.

Comment: Thanks, the homography does indeed show to be fully populated when starting from index 0.

My objective is a take a point from the image and transform it to ground plane coordinates. I believe I have findHomography() working correctly. WarpPerspective seems to be focused on images. What do I need to do to transform just an x,y point from an image? How do I populate the information?

Comment: You are having a wrong idea about images. Images are matrixes, an array of numbers if you will. Any point in your source image will warp. If your picture/matrix contains only one point (actually pixelvector) only one point will be transformed.

Comment: @Will I may have misunderstood what you where going for. If you just want to transform single points. I have added it to my answer.

Comment: I'm close (working on extracting the data via the correct Mat elements/types) , have to get back to this in the evening, thanks for your excellent assistance so far.

Comment: This is the answer! Thank you very much, your input was crucial to my understanding of this capability. Cheers!